# How find this equation all solution $2a^2-1=b^{2013}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

let $a,b\in \mathbb Z$, and such $$2a^2-1=b^{2013}$$

find all value $a,b$

I think $(a,b)=(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,1)$ is solution, and have other solution.  Thank you everyone

Comment: As $3\mid2013$ I would try to prove non-existence of other solutions of $2a^2-1=c^3$. An elliptic curve, but probably has some trick method.

Comment: Thank you all same, @JyrkiLahtonen

Comment: According to me, we can prove that $\frac{b^{2013}}2 + \frac12$ is a perfect square only for the solutions you gave above then I think we might get something.

Comment: this problem How to prove $$\dfrac{b^{2013}}{2}+\dfrac{1}{2}$$ is a  perfect.

Comment: And where do you get these questions from? These questions are so interesting..... You just made me curious...

Comment: @Rohinb97, This problem is my frend ask me,I think this problem is from compition

Comment: Obviously b cannot be even, it must be odd. Also the trick in questions like this is basically same:logically prove that the above term is not a perfect square for large values of b. Completing the square according to me might help...

Comment: This problem is very interesting,Hope someone can use nice methods

Comment: If it is from an ongoing competition (as seems possible given the appearance of 2013), you should tell us (and wait until deadline has passed). Otherwise it may get ugly, allegations of cheating and such.

Comment: yes,I'm a math teacher and  it's deadline

Comment: Try showing it's congruent to 0mod4 and 1mod8 to see if it's only for odd or even perfect squares or both.

Answer (score 3):

Following Jyrki's suggestion, set $c=b^{671}$ and the equation becomes $$2a^2=c^3+1$$
Multiply both sides by 8 to get $$(4a)^2=(2c)^3+8$$
This is a [Mordell curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordell_curve), which have finitely many solutions.  In this case the constant is $8$, and [here](http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+) we can find the only integral solutions $$(4a,2c)\in \{(0,-2),(3,1),(-3,1), (4,2), (-4,2), (312,46), (-312,46)\}$$
This gives $$(a,c)\in \{(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,1),(78,23),(-78,23)\}$$

However only the first three give $c$ that is a 671st power.  This confirms that there are three solutions in the integers.

> Followup: We may replace $2013$ with $3(2k+1)$ for any integral $k\ge 2$ and get the same result.

Comment: Hello, @vadim123,I can't Open the Mordell curve,can you send to me?

Comment: http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/MORDELL+ it's a text file

Comment: Thank you @vadim123, where are this proof? with this $$c^3+1=2a^2$$ has only $$(a,c)\in\{(0,-1),(1,1),(-1,1),(78,23),(-78,23)\}$$?

Comment: Mordell curves are of the form $y^2=x^3+n$, and there are only finitely many integral solutions for any fixed $n$.  For more details, see the wikipedia link I posted.  The second link I posted (see http://tnt.math.se.tmu.ac.jp/simath/MORDELL/) gives the specific solutions for all $n$ with $|n|<10000$.  They were computed using computer software.

Comment: Thank you, I hope see this equation $x^3+1=2y^3$ integer solution methods? But I can't find it,can you link ? Thank you very much

Comment: I've uploaded the file (and a pdf of the first 10 pages) for you.  Here's the [link](http://www.sendspace.com/filegroup/QbnOP1uprFAtpnXQkjEn4g).

Comment: The methods to solve these are difficult, as they are elliptic curves.  See also http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MordellCurve.html

Comment: Thank you, if you let $b^{667}=x$ this solution Become less？